# I am having an error upon importing cloud_firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm having the following error when running my flutter application when I import :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

The errors :

```
/C:/Users/Dell5587/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Dell5587/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Dell5587/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/Dell5587/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
```

Some clarification or a solution would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

When I remove the import statement, the error doesn't come up and the app runs fine.

Comment: I resolved it by simply running flutter clean and adding the dependency back again. Later restarting the VSCode did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This library **cloud_firestore** included dependencies **cloud_firestore_platform_interface** and I think solve this problem :

- `flutter clean`
- remove manually folder `../pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0`
- write this line in command `flutter pub add cloud_firestore_platform_interface`
- `flutter run`

Comment: Where can I find the cloud_firestore_platform_interface file?

Comment: this path `C:/Users/Dell5587/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org` remove folder `cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0`

Comment: Still no luck :(. The app reloads fine when the import statement is not added. as soon as I add the import statement the error is thrown.

Comment: show me version `cloud_firestore ` in file pubspec.yaml

Comment: `cloud_firestore: any`

Comment: try , remove `cloud_firestore: any` and `flutter clean` and write command this line `flutter pub add cloud_firestore & flutter pub add cloud_firestore_platform_interface`

Comment: when i add the `pub add cloud_firestore` I get the following error `The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

Because cloud_firestore 3.1.15 requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of cloud_firestore match >3.1.15 <4.0.0, cloud_firestore ^3.1.15 is forbidden.
So, because demo_app_1 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.15, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because demo_app_1 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.15, version solving failed.)
exit code 1`

Comment: change version SDK to `sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: I changed the environment sdk as follows: `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0" ` 
I get the following error:
`[demo_app_1] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in demo_app_1...                      
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

Because demo_app_1 requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because demo_app_1 requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1`

Comment: I'm quiet confused by this as when I run flutter --version i get the following result
`Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.854 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ec20ea80ad (16 hours ago) • 2022-05-21 16:28:06 -0400
Engine • revision 1bfe551d6b
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-142.0.dev) • DevTools 2.13.1`

The dart sdk is at version 2.18.0

Comment: ok , write `flutter channel dev` and check version sdk and insert version file pubspec.yaml  `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutte run`